# How to merge 2 mysql databases with same structure and common entries

Tags: mysql, restore, dump

I am not sure that there is a simple solution to my problem but ...

I dumped a mysql database from a production machine to run migration tests on a test machine. 
Tests went well so 2 days later I did the migration on the production machine after dumping the database again (for safety).

There was a problem during migration and the database was corrupted so I had to restore the dumped database. The second migration attempt went OK.

Now here is the thing : I realised a few days later that I made a mistake and restored not the dump I made just before the migration but the first one I made 2 days ago for testing purpose.

I know, I suck, I hate myself today ...

I now have this to try something :

- the first dump (but I don't think it is useful)
- the second dump which was the one I should have restored but didn't
- the current database with a 2 day gap, it contains data of the first dump plus a few days of new entries from after the restoration.

I wish to merge these databases so I end up with one which contains everything.

Since the second dump and the current database have most entries in common I have to ignore duplicate but the ignore option (if I understand well) is based on primary keys and it would also ignore some new entries because they have the same primary keys than the one from the 2 day gap. So I am stuck with my own little knowledge.

I am not a specialist of mysql so I hope someone here can help me with that.

Is there a way to merge the databases in a way that only real duplicates (entire row is identical) are ignored ?

Comment: Man.  That sucks.  Someone may know of an easy way.  But I do not. Trying to think of how I would handle. Does every table in the db have an auto_incremented id?  How big is the database?  How many tables?  2hat size tables?

Comment: The database size is almost 2 Go. Every table has an id column which is the primary key and auto increment. There are several hundreds tables but a lot are empty (this is a web application database with unused options).

Comment: I seriously think i would look at MAX id in each table in the second dump and then todays. I would insert the difference into the two day dump. I would probably do this in PHP though. Hopefully a DBA comes along with a better idea.

Comment: That was what I thought too but how to extract all the new entries and insert them without their AI id ? Plus I don't thing I would have the courage to do this manually on each table tey are too many of them. Is there a way to extract into sql file only entries added after a given datetime (without their primary key) ?

Comment: Not that I know of.  You would extract the full table with the ids>MAX id in two day dump. You would then have to do an insert spelling out the columns.

Comment: In this case you first need to find alle the records that are now missing from the current database, this should be pretty easy. You would then try to reenter the found data in the existing database as if it was new data. This way the auto-increment columns, and everything else, would do its work as normal. Moreso, a lot of the needed data entry routines should already exist. However, I have no idea if this is achievable with your database. PS: You would normally keep a log of everything that was entered into the database, do you have such a log? (this is sometimes called a 'backup')

Comment: One problem with the keys may be that they are used as foreign key in other tables. Any solution you come up with will need to resolve these keys.